# How do I resolve the errors resulting from the JaCoCo maven plugin?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jacoco

I added JaCoCo to my maven pom file but this results in many errors. How do I resolve these? 
This is my first time configuring a pom / maven setup. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried running mvn clean install site prior to adding JaCoCo and it is working fine. Adding the JaCoCo dependency and plugin info then results in many errors. Can't find any solution on the web so far.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>0.20</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
</plugin>
```

Some of the many errors are pasted below. Recurring theme is [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 18, column 13.

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 1
>   problem was encountered while building the effective model for
>   org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:1.0-alpha-6 [ERROR]
>   'distributionManagement.status' must not be specified. @ line 18,
>   column 13
>
> org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were
>   encountered while processing the POMs: [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin is missing. @ line 84,
>   column 15 [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be
>   specified. @ line 236, column 13
>
> Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 2
>   problems were encountered while building the effective model for
>   org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.5 [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin is missing. @ line 84,
>   column 15 [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be
>   specified. @ line 236, column 13
>
> org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were
>   encountered while processing the POMs: [WARNING]
>   'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 13,
>   column 15 [ERROR] 'distributionManagement.status' must not be
>   specified. @ line 43, column 13

Comment: You don't need the plugin dependency in your pom.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How can I check the code coverage of my tests without the dependency in my pom? Other sources suggest I add the dependency such as: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.8.4

Comment: Your plugin config looks good. The error says that you haven't specified versions for other plugins:maven-surefire-plugin and maven-site-plugin

Comment: plugin represents an executable code in your build. Providing dependency for the plugin is not required. Just make sure that the plugin is located inside the <build><plugins>...<\plugins><build> section. Whereas dependency section should be out of <build> section. To make sure the JaCoCo works fine, you can just run some of the goals in the cmd: mvn jacoco:report